# mySQL: How to select 3 random cities for each id_country in one table

Tags: mysql

I need to select 3 random cities from one table for each country.
(id_city, name_en, id_country)

I did find one worked example but it doesn't work in mysql
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6340b1/3

I need to convert that code to mysql or find another way to do this

Comment: Create stored procedure to do this stuff. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try that

```
SELECT id_country, id_city, name_en
FROM (
SELECT id_country_id, id_city, name_en
FROM {your_table}
ORDER BY RAND()
) t
GROUP BY id_country
```